# static_cast between 'unrelated types'

Tags: c++, static-cast

If I have this class structure:

```
class A
{
public: 
    int a;
    void funcA(){a = 0;}
};

class B
{
public:
    int b;
    void funcB(){b = 0;}
};

class C: public A, public B
{
public:
    int c;
    void funcC(){c = 0;}
};
```

Why can I perform this cast?

```
A* pA = new A;

C* pC = static_cast<C*> (pA);
B* pB = static_cast<B*> (pC);

pB->funcB();
```

A and B are unrelated, are they not?

Comment: This sequence of casts would be fine if you started out with `A *pA = new C;`. So neither the language nor the compiler is going to stop you making them: the problem isn't the casts, it's the input value.

Comment: The cast from `pA` to `C*` is already undefined behavior.

Comment: There isn't a 'problem' here, I was wondering why this is permissable. The compiler *would* stop me if the classes were not in the same hierarchy, yes? I assumed the cast from pA to C* was OK since C is derived from A.

Comment: @QuoVadis: exactly, the cast from `A*` to `C*` is called a "downcast", and it's defined if you pass it the address of an A object that happens to be the base-class subobject of a C object. It's undefined otherwise. The compiler here doesn't try to work out what you're passing it, although with a bit of data-flow analysis it could in principle detect that you've done it wrong.

Comment: You can use `dynamic_cast` to perform a downcast that does check at runtime whether you've passed an instance of `C`, but that's only available if `A` has at least one virtual function, because the meta-data needed for the check comes with the virtual dispatch mechanism. So not for this example.

Answer (score 6):

They may be unrelated, but the compiler doesn't do inter-cast diagnosis here.

It just says "Oh, `C` is a derived class of `A`, that's legal as far as I'm concerned".
In the next line it says "Oh, `B` is a base class of `C`, that's legal as far as I'm concerned".
And that's about it. In your case, `C` links `A` and `B` between casts.

Comment: @Quo: C++ just gives you enough rope to hang yourself with. It's up to you how to use it correctly.

Comment: @Quo: Or in other words, **C++ is not your babysitter**.